# How to handle TPH in the case of M-M relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

If I have (M-M) relationship from entity framework power tools like this :

[image]

Now if i have two categories :

1. Iron
2. Cement

The `Iron` related by `Company` through (`MonthQ,Production,localSales`)

The  `Cement` related by `Company` through (`MonthQ,Production,Exporting`)

This means that `Exporting` is null in the case of `Iron` And `localSales` is null in the case of `Cement`.

---

Should i create two child classes (Iron,Cement) inherit from my base class Category ?

How to handle this case ?

---

According to the comments : 
I will try to clarify the required by forms mock-ups  :

The requirement some thing like that :

[image]

Comment: Your model and naming look strange. With MonthQ and FirstDate columns this isn't really an MxM link table, is it? I could see a model with LocalSales and ExportSales entities here. Will you really never sell Cement locally?

Comment: The model should definitely have a CompanyCategory table, having one or more Sales records. But it's impossible to give any solid model recommendations without knowing the business. To me this is "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @HenkHolterman : i upload the user requirement for this part.

Comment: @GertArnold : I edit the question with more explanation . Could you look at it please .

Comment: I'm really sorry, but this doesn't make it any more clear to me. It only confirms to me that your data model needs revision. It isn't normalized well. `CompanyCategory` should only store the fact that company A has categories Iron and Cement, etc. Then there should be other tables that store facts about `CompanyCategory`s, i.e. having a foreign key to `CompanyCategory`. Deciding about a good data model isn't trivial. I think it's always too broad (and opinion-based) for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @GertArnold : i do my best to illustrate the user point view . according to the forms , he needs four forms two forms per category (`Two for Iron`, `Two for Cement`) and according to him , there are common fields(`MonthQ,Production`) and different fields ( `localSales` for `Iron` ,`Exporting` for `Cement`). So i thought to make base category and (`Iron`,`Cement`) sub classes inherit from category and the relationship between `Company` and `Category` m-m but little confused how to do something like that using `EF`.

Comment: The screen suggests that CategoryId could be an enum instead of an auto-increment. There are no clues whether the StartDate related and Production related columns should be in 1 table. Nothing (yet) that requires inheritance.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : Could you suggest your modifications on the model in an answer clarifying that please

Comment: No, I agree with Gert that this is too broad. We already gave you some pointers to rethink your model.